# Can FindProxyForURL() discern the HTTP-method of the request?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, proxy, javascript

I'd like my `FindProxyForURL()` to recommend a different proxy depending on the HTTP-method of the request -- `GET`, `POST`, or `PUT`.

For example, the `GET`s can be routed through a *caching* proxy, whereas the `POST`s and the `PUT`s would go `DIRECT`... Or someone may prefer to add security to their submissions by routing the `POST`s through Tor, but without slowing down the regular -- `GET`-based -- browsing.

The standard [PAC-functions](https://findproxyforurl.com/pac-functions/) provide no mechanism for this, but, maybe, Firefox (or Chrome?) do offer some sort of extension?